# Shortcut to jump to the previous white space in a bash command line

Tags: bash

To jump to the previous word in a command line, I use Alt + `b`.
However, the names of my files are pretty long and look like this:

`2018_09_03_abcdef_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt`

When I want to change the name of these files, I use the command `mv` and a shortcut** that permits me to paste the first word/argument (the current name of the file). This gives me the following command:

`$ mv 2018_09_03_abcdef_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt 2018_09_03_abcdef_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt`

Then I either want to change the date of the day and/or the first letters of the file name to get for example the final command line:

`$ mv 2018_09_03_abcdef_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt 2018_09_04_ABcd1234_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt`

To make the change at the beginning of the file name, I have to type the shortcut Alt + `b` several times since this shortcut considers every letters separated by an underscore as a word.

I would like to be able to jump directly to the beginning of the name (not the beginning of the line) to modify it. A shortcut targeting the white space would be ideal.

I have not been able to find such a shortcut that would skip the underscores and go directly to the previous white space.

Did anyone already create a shortcut in bash that allows you to do this?

Would the only possible way to accomplish this be to switch from emacs mode to vi mode (`set -o vi`) and use the vi shortcut:
`F` + `space` 
?

Thank you very much in advance!

** The shortcut I found to paste the previous word in the current command line and paste it in the same current command line uses Alt + `j` and has to be added in the '~/.inputrc' file (followed by `bind -f ~/.inputrc`):

`"\ej":"!#:$\e^"`

Comment: If previous occurrence of `space` is what you want, you should be able to search backwards for space by using `^R` followed by `space`. Repeat `^R` to search back further. This is actually a history search, but starts with current position in the current line, so should work also for this purpose.

Comment: You are posting your question at StackOverflow but this question is not really about programming. Maybe you would have more luck at https://superuser.com

Comment: Thank you very much vdavid! Great suggestion! I just posted my question on this site.

Comment: Ondrej K., this actually works well! Using `^R` (Ctrl + `r`) followed by `space` does relocate the cursor to the white space I am looking for. That does save me time! Thank you very much! Your comment is definitely a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are [several shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/47735/600015) to navigate bash command line. Here's another [list](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/).
Assuming cursor is at the end of the line, it could jump to `03` (day part) by typing **<kbd>Meta</kbd>+7 <kbd>Meta</kbd>+b** (2 keystrokes without releasing <kbd>Meta</kbd> key).
Now, for the file name changes, [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) could be used to get a command like this that provides the second argument from expansion.

```
mv 2018_09_{03_abc,04_ABC}def_ghijkl_mnopqr_stuvwx_yz.txt
```